# Get the next highest value in a horizontal array

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have a row of numbers 1,2,3....20 (in 20 cols A  to T). I want to get the next highest number after say 10.5 (in column U). I am looking for 11 as the the answer (in Col V). About to give trying - need to run formula more than 6,000 rows.

Comment: What does "I have say" mean? :S Although to find the second, use LARGE(RANGE, Number). You also write you have values from A to T, but apparently the value in Column U is 10.5. Is the U column the value you want to look up from?

Comment: Are the numbers ordered?  Where are you looking for the next highest number (entire row or only to the right?  What defines that 10.5 in column U is the basis (value specified somewhere, cell identified somewhere)?  Given that, how do you know where to search?  Is that the same basis for every line or is each line different?

Comment: @Dave Should be "I have, say, ..." as in, "I have, for example, ..."

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with `INDEX` and `MATCH` on an ordered range:
`=INDEX(A1:T1,MATCH(U1,A1:T1,1)+1)`

[image]

If the data isn't ordered, then use this array formula (need to finalize with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER):
`=MIN(IF(U1<A1:T1,A1:T1,""))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for identifying this answer as correct @Excel2013 - if you feel your whole query has been answered, it would be good to mark this answer as 'correct' using the green tick on the left of the answer. :)